# Importing Data into Elastic Search from R

Tags: r, json, elasticsearch

I am trying to import data from an API call (and processed the JSON Output in **R**) into an index at elastic search.

`stored` is a dataframe containing 20 obs. along 113 variables. However, elastic search copies only 7 out of 20 obs. into the index. Those are correctly transferred in terms of values.

Still, I cannot explain where and why I am missing the other 13 observations.

The code I am using:

```
stored <- fromJSON(API_URL)
stored <- stored[['results']]

connect(es_base = "xxx.xxx.x.xx", es_port = xxxx)
connection()

docs_bulk(stored, index="data", raw = FALSE, chunk_size = 100000)
```

Comment: (I'm author of `elastic`) I'm not sure you've given enough details for me to help. `chunk_size` is ignored if the number is larger than your input, which appears to be only 20 rows, correct? Also, which version of R, Elasticsearch, and `elastic` are you using

Comment: Hej Sckott, I am using R version 3.2.4 (2016 - 03 - 10) on a Windows 7 x64 machine and elastic_0.6.0. I just copied the last version of the code I used. As a first step I will update my R as i realized the package were launched on R  3.2.5. I would love to support you with more details on the case if needed.

Comment: With new version of R I am facing the same problem.

Comment: The only thing I can think is if you can share some of the data with me, or share a fake dataset that also causes that error

Comment: You can email me, my email is here https://github.com/sckott

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Sckott, we were able to solve the problem.

The Json file from the API Call were not 100% - UTF8 encoded. By using fromJSON for the URL-Call it entered additional characters to the data. However, adding a readLines avoids the problem. The final code i used were:

```
Output_FT <- fromJSON(readLines(BWURL_x), flatten = TRUE)
stored <- Output_FT[['results']]
connect(es_base = "xxx.xxx.x.xx", es_port = xxxx)
connection()
docs_bulk(stored, index="data")
```

Best,